# Is using external web-hosting a good solution for holding images to be used for hot-linking from other sites?

Tags: web-hosting, image-hosting

To clarify the title I will give my scenario while trying to keep it generic:

I work for a company that will expand their eCommerce to controlled markets (think Amazon, eBay), uploading thousands of products to these sites. The controlled market we're going for has a strict size restriction on uploaded images which is several GB below what we need.

As a solution, I am looking to external web-hosting solutions that will hold our product images then hot-linking them inside the controlled market. Obviously, we will pay for the amount of storage, GET requests when images are viewed on the market, etc.

My question, therefore, is **is this the right way to approach this?**

NB Expanding storage space on the controlled market is out of the question as it is very much overpriced.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, most people use a CDN for this. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Like closetnoc commented on your original post, if you're going to be uploading thousands of photos for use on external websites with the desire to manage them yourself, using a CDN or a service like Amazon's S3 might be worth looking into.

With Amazon's S3, you pay for the storage that you use and don't have to worry about potential influxes of traffic, as the service runs on Amazon's AWS and should be able to scale as needed. In fact, Amazon says that the service offers 99.999999999% durability!

It should be noted that there may be a bit of a learning curve when first setting up and using a cloud-based storage service like S3, but it does offer quite a bit of flexibility